# Tascam DR-40 and DR-100MKII - Record into multiple files

Tags: tascam

Is it possible with the Tascam DR-40 or DR-100MKII, to record into multiple tracks from different inputs? So, if I connect 2 mics, the other sending the sound into different file.

Comment: Why would you need this functionality, you can simply record in stereo and split the l an r channel after recording?

Comment: Because what if I want to record ambiant sound of the room or industrial building 10 meters far from the talent? Sometimes pretty useful to record into different files from different sources in the same time.

Comment: Get another recorder with more than 2 inputs? Or use a note app or notebook to write it down old skool.

Comment: Return back to my question: possible this with the Tascams? I heard Zooms know this, but I prefer Tascam audio examples on the net more.

Comment: Do you own a Tascam device? Have you downloaded the manual and checked for the possibility? BTW I still don't get why you'd want 2 files for the same take, in post production that would be a problem for the dialogue editor. You can record a close and distant source to a stereo file and split it up later, why do you need 2 files? When is that usefull?

Comment: It is useful on the ceremony when for example you record the priest's mic and the couple's lav mics. Or on the party at night, when you catch the DJ's signal (where a quest told speech with mic) and you have lav mics on couple. By the way, I asked Tascam Pre-Sales support: "Dear Tascam! I want to ask you, is it possible with the Tascam DR-100MkII, to record in the same time to different files from different input sources? Yours sincerely, XY" No answer. I guess not possible. Zoom H5, H6 then... But on the audio samples, I like Tascam output more. :(

Comment: There are big recorders which can do this, but they are out of my budget. I want a hand-held recorder with the same multi-recording functionality, where you can monitor every input in the same time. Sometimes I want to use this recorder for photojournalist projects to record only audio, sometimes use it for wedding cinematography, other video works. I prefer more Tascam DR-100MkII audio samples over Zoom H6. It's just not hurting my ears so like the Zoom on laud levels (all of the two are great, but T even better). But recording multiple files in the same time is just better bang for my buck.

Comment: Ok it's more clear to me know, you want "monophonic multichannel" recording, like on SD and other bigger recorders. I think you're going to have to save up for that, if Tascam doesn't support that. Otherwise, use batch conversion and split the stereo file, rename the l and r channels matching their content.

Comment: Well, thinking about it, it's really not a big deal breaker to record different inputs into the left/right channel. Rode NTG-3, lav mics, etc. record in mono anyway. But huge importance for me able to record with timecode. DR-40 can do this, but I not find any info about DR-100MKII. This will be my first audio device and I want the best that suits my needs. Zoom H6 with 4XLR (+2 with extender) is great, BUT I not like the sound... :( More complex and better field recorders out of my budget.